# Use variable outside switch statement + asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, variables

In my Index Action in my Controller I have this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
{
    var model;
    ViewBag.CitySortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "City_desc" : "";
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "City_desc":
            model = this.UnitOfWork.AddressRepository.Get().OrderBy(a => a.City);
            break;
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

This doesn't work, I always get the error: `Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized`

Why doesn't this work and how can I fix this?

Comment: What is the type of model?

Comment: With variables declared with var, the type is inferred from whatever is immediately assigned. You need to declare it with its specific type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why doesn't this work

Two reasons:

- You're trying to use `var` without specifying an initial value. You can't do that - the compiler can't infer the type.
- You're trying to read from the `model` variable when it may not be initialized - if `sortOrder` *isn't* `City_desc` what would you expect to be returned? And what would that type be?

> and how can I fix this?

That depends on what you want to happen if `sortOrder` isn't `City_desc`. Work out what value you'd want to return, and make sure it's returned.

Basically, you can't read from a local variable until it's *definitely assigned* - in other words, until the compiler can prove (by the rules of C#) that by the time you get there, it will have been assigned a value.

In terms of the implicit typing - are you always going to use the same type for your view? If so, just explicitly declare the type of `model`, as well as fixing the definite assignment part. If not, I'd consider returning *within* the `switch`/`case` statement - I don't think your `model` local variable is actually helping you much.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is that the type of the `model` variable cannot be inferred if you just declare it with `var model;`.

You should explicitly declare its type.

Also, as Jon Skeet correctly pointed out, you must initialize your `model` somehow before the `return`... call. Try to imagine what you `model`'s value is if `sortOrder` is not "City_desc"...

Comment: On its own, that won't be enough - because the variable still won't be definitely assigned on the last line where it's read.

Answer (score 1):

> Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized

Yes will have to initialize it inline to make it work.

```
var model = default(MyType);//This should work
```

Or just declare the type explicitly.

```
MyType model = default(MyType);//Or null if it is a reference type
```

Comment: That will compile - but it may well not be desirable. The OP really needs to think about what they want to happen if the sort order isn't the one their code currently handles.

Comment: You're right @JonSkeet, Ideally it should throw exception or return null :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize an implicitly declared variable before using it. A simple example:

```
var x;

if(true)
    x = "true";
```

This will get you the same error. This should be hapening:

```
var x = "";

if(true)
    x = "true";
```

Same goes for your code. Initialize it before using it. Say your model is of type `AddressViewModel`, then this should work:

```
var model = new AddressViewModel();
ViewBag.CitySortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "City_desc" : "";
switch (sortOrder)
{
    case "City_desc":
        model = this.UnitOfWork.AddressRepository.Get().OrderBy(a => a.City);
        break;
}
return View(model);
```